# My code doesn't run it says there is a circular import error I'm try to load the home view so that it redirects me

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

I am working on a django project, but it returns 
the included urlconf "myapp.urls"does not appear to have any patterns in it.

I tried checking my views to ensure I imported everything correctly

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import home
from accounts.views import login_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',home),
    path('accounts/login/', login_view),
]
```

I expect the site to run and redirect me to the login page

This is my views in the same directory with the urls.py

```py
@login_required
def home(request):
    return render(request,"home.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't have a problem, send the repository link

Answer (score 0):

Include this In your settings.py

## settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = "/accounts/logout/"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = " "
```